# unwanted links in html programming (mails and phone numbers)

Tags: php, html

i have a php page that sends mails to the visitors and in the body of the mail there is an email address which turns into a link and has an underline.
this link should be just an address not a link to send a mail to it.
another thing is that i can't change it's style using CSS or Something else.
i have the same problem with phone numbers. i don't want it to be a link.
how can i disable this link behavior?

this is the code for sending the email:

```
$mail = "getter@example.com";
$subject = "mail address";
$body = "<p>This is The Email Address</p><br><span>responder@example.com</span>";
$headers = "From: Gifters <info@example.com>"
mail($mail, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

thanks for reading this.

Comment: Edit: I understand you're question, answering now.

Comment: @Nicolas I believe he wants to display the email address in plain text without it becoming parsed into a hyperlink.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent gmail to create link for URL and email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988534/prevent-gmail-to-create-link-for-url-and-email)

Comment: Try testing this with different email services. What you're describing sounds like something that may be caused by the email service parsing the email before being presented to the viewer, and making things like phone numbers and email addresses clickable. HTML doesn't have anything "special" regarding phone numbers, but you may have a Skype extension in your web browser that changes it to a Skype link, for example.

Comment: To add onto what Joe said, making stuff links that probably should be helps people who may not use the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the email in empty tags and hope that the mail clients are not smart enough to see through it:

```
$body = "<p>This is The Email Address</p><br /><span>responder</span><span>@</span><span>example.</span><span>.com</span>";
```

Comment: If it worked try reducing the `span` tags to just having them around the `@` sign and `.`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of e-mail clients transform telephone numbers, email addresses, ... automatically into links.

You could try and avoid these filters by using & instead of @

but then agian, why is this bad? Everything to make it easier for the user is a good thing, no?

Comment: This email address is a username i want it to be a simple text followed by the password

Comment: "Easier for the user" is exactly why we sometimes need to _avoid_ spurious (and wrong) hyperlinks. For example, if the receiving system is an automated ticketing system that strips HTML back to plain text (which is good from a safety perspective), and includes the hyperlink as visible text, this can be actively misleading to the person dealing with the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is add CSS to your email's surrounding tags that way you can remove the pointer cursor and underline:

```
$mail = "getter@example.com";
$subject = "mail address";
$body = "<p>This is The Email Address</p><br><span class='nonLink'>responder@example.com</span>";
$headers = "From: Gifters <info@example.com>"
mail($mail, $subject, $body, $headers);

<style>
    .nonLink {
         text-decoration: none;
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
    }
</style>
```

You could also put your CSS directly in-line with the HTML, however, this is bad practice.

`text-decoration: none;` will remove your underline and (blue?) color

`pointer-events: none;` will remove your hyperlink

`cursor: default;` will bring back the default cursor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the html code equivalent of `@` which is `&#64;` ?

Not sure if it will work :

```
$body = "<p>This is The Email Address</p><br><span>responder&#64;example.com</span>";
```