# Prevent Gmail from creating links for email addresses in email message body

Tags: html, typescript, email

I've read the old answers at [Prevent Gmail from creating links for URLs and email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988534/prevent-gmail-from-creating-links-for-urls-and-email-addresses).

Apparently Gmail has updated, and those answers don't work.

I've also tried using multiple of those strategies combined:

```
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988534/prevent-gmail-from-creating-links-for-urls-and-email-addresses
 */
export function getUnlinkableEmailAddressHtml(emailAddress: string): string {
  const ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE = '\uFEFF'; // https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm
  const AT = '@';
  const pieces = emailAddress.split(AT);
  const username = `<span>${pieces[0]}</span>${ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE}`;
  const domain = pieces[1] ?? '';
  const atDomain = domain ? `${AT}${domain}` : '';
  return `${username}${atDomain}`;
}
```

But this still doesn't prevent Gmail from creating a `mailto:` hyperlink of email addresses in the message body.

What solutions work today in 2023?